# Call phantomjs from webpage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have some HTML reports generated by Classic ASP and I need them converted to PDF.
Searching for a solution I found out phantomJS, which has 'rasterize.js', a functionality that would take the HTML and output it as PDF.

The problem is that I can´t figure out how to call phantomJS from my original/current webpage.

The idea I had in mind is, my current webpage calls phatomjs sending its HTML content then phantomjs would call rasterize.js and output the PDF to the server, then I would get the name of the recently created PDF and serve it back to the client.

Is there a way this could be done?

Comment: To clarify, phantomjs would be running on the server, not the client. Correct?

Comment: Yes, the phantomjs is on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Phantomjs is not the made for running in the browser as far as I know.

You have different options for this:

1. use a libaray like https://parall.ax/products/jspdf which has a fromHTML method to render html content to pdf
2. Send your html content to a remote server which renders a PDF and send it back to you, a friend of mine contributes to this https://github.com/piobyte/flamingo. It it a server which does this.
3. Use some sort of messaging (e.g. websocket) to inform a remote server to render your page and give the user a download link.

Comment: I think I´ll give jsPDF a try. It´s been said that the HTML renderer is at its early stages but I´ll see. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can call phantomjs from the server by shelling out to it.
In most languages that will look like:

```
`phantomjs myscript.js`
```